# Unable to consistently update nested objects in Realm

Tags: objective-c, realm

I'm trying to do some simple updates in a nested object and I'm noticing that its not happening consistently.

Lets hypothetically assume the following classes are involved:

```
@interface Dog : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@property NSData   *picture;
@property NSInteger age;
@end

@interface Person : RLMObject
@property NSString             *name;
@property RLMArray<Dog *><Dog> *dogs;
@end
```

If the server passes me a Person object with an updated dog name, currently I would just do (in Psuedocode)

```
for (Dog *dog in person.dogs)
{
     dog.name = updatedDogName;
}

[defaultRealm beginWriteTransaction];
[defaultRealm addOrUpdateObject:person];
[defaultRealm commitWriteTransaction];
```

ASSUMPTIONS:
 1) Person and the respective Dog object has unique primary keys
 2) Person and the respective Dog object has already persisted in the DB, and I am merely updating the Dog object through the Person object.

Am I doing something wrong here? I've noticed the update happens roughly half the time only.

Comment: Hello Jasper. Is there any way you can create a sample project demonstrating this behavior and email it to help@realm.io? Being able to reproduce the problem will help us to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Just as an observation, if you're changing just the dogs' names in this transaction, it's not necessary to call `[defaultRealm addOrUpdateObject:person];` as well. In this case, since your `Person` doesn't have a primary key, this would guarantee a new copy of `Person` is added to the database each time you call it.

Comment: @AustinZ, I think the problem stems from using writeCopyToURL to compact the size of the database while a write transaction is going on. I'm currently working on tracking down where else I need to add in autoreleasepools to try to lessen this from happening. Is there a smart way to if there are any write transactions going on, or if there are any realm objects left in memory that is connected to an instance of the default realm?

Comment: @TiM so assuming my person object has a primary key, and already persists in my database, would I then need to add in addOrUpdateObject? Or is that still unnecessary?

We have a bit of a unique situation as we are using as much standalone objects as possible. This stems from because in the earlier versions of Realm (before 1.0), there were problems with Realm not compacting itself automatically. This would eventually lead to the file size to being massive and crashing the app. I will update the example to give you a better idea of what i mean.

Comment: For `[RLMRealm addOrUpdateObject]`, that particular `person` instance should be a Realm-less copy (e.g. `person.realm == nil`) for it to be of any value. The values of its properties will be applied to the equivalent object with the same primary key in the database, or it itself will be added if an object with that primary key doesn't exist. If `person` was retrieved from a Realm query, there's not really much point calling that method, since you can just update the properties directly inside the write transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem stems from calling writeCopyToURL while an object with a Realm instance attached to it is in use (e.g. `person.realm != nil`). Use autoreleasepools more liberally to try to lessen the odds of things like this happening.